# trigger an alarm sms for android

Tags: android, sms

sir, i want to trigger an alarm when the user receives a sms containing a particular keyword, then provide the user with an alertdialog to reply back with a predefined message. in my code, i can't seem to get the alarm to work. it just displays the alertdialog. also, if possible, i want to use the default alarm of the phone and set it off even in silent mode. i want to replace the sms received tone with an alarm. please help me. thanks in advance.

```
public class EAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String sender;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) 
    { 
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) 
            pdusObj[i]); 
            sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    } 

    for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("firealert")) {


            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(300);

            Uri alert = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
            if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) 
            {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                //mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "alarm started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }//end if

            Intent openInterface = new Intent("proj.receiver.RECEIVERINTERFACE");
            openInterface.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(openInterface);

        }//end if
    }//end for

}// end onreceive
```

Comment: @PaulR: Looks like Android to me.

Comment: OK - thanks - I'll add an `android` tag for now and if it's wrong someone else can correct it later...